# android draw circle badge on top on bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, badge

I want to add a badge with the number of pending events above the menu icon of the application, but as you can see in the image below I have some problems. I'm unable to make the circle opaque, I don't want to see the grey lines behind the circle and the new image is cut on the top

I want to use it on the logo icon of the action bar (the home icon), not in any other menu item of the action bar so custom action view is not an option

[image]

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);
    bm = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);

    Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    //circlePaint.setAlpha(255);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint(); 
    textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    textPaint.setTextSize(23); 
    textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawCircle(bm.getWidth()/6, bm.getHeight()/5, 13, circlePaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, bm.getWidth()/7 + 5, bm.getHeight()/3, textPaint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560526/how-to-implement-dynamic-values-on-menu-item-in-android

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is called `Android View badger` and you should check this lovely **[TUTORIAL](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)** or **[this](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/RefreshActionItem)** ...i am sure it will help you a lot ...enjoy :) :)

Comment: I want to use it on the logo icon of the action bar (the home icon), not in any other menu item of the action bar. I tried to use View badger but doesn't show anything

Comment: Above link says Badging Action Bar items is currently not supported. He needs icon on Action bar item.

Comment: +1 for the ViewBadger "Tutorial" link (Git hub repo actually).  Nice library.

Comment: github link donot take menuItem context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **relative layout** for this things, instead draw from canvas.

Here a [nice tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044828/drawing-number-badge-like-iphone-in-android) how do it with **relative layout**.

EDIT:

For [ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057782/dynamic-drawable-icon-for-actionbar-menu-item-android-actionbarsherlock)

Comment: I can't because it's the icon of the actionbar and only accept drawable

Comment: okay, there a good answer for actionbar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057782/dynamic-drawable-icon-for-actionbar-menu-item-android-actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu item in res/menu and set the actionLayout to your layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/icn_menu_posts"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

and your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <!-- Menu Item Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bkg_actionbar_notify_off" />

    <!-- Badge Count -->    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_orange_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in onCreateOptionsMenu of your activity do something like this...

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.badge, menu);

    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    TextView tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
    tv.setText("12");
}
```

Also checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288989/how-to-get-text-on-an-actionbar-icon/16648170#16648170).

Comment: I forgot to mention it wasn't a normal menu item inside the action bar, I want to add the badge to the home icon